# Define on demand input dynamically

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need to define an input for load on demand settings via Ironpython script, is it possible? What I need is this:

- User fills a multilinetext box with a list of input
- String is split and passed as a property of a string list container
- This property is a defined input for load-on-demand

Up to this point, everything works fine, but the point is that user can insert type_A input or type_B input and I want to realize a script like this:

- if user pass type_A input then search in COLUMN_A
- else search in COLUMN_B

In other words I need to define on demand input dynamically through Ironpython. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you show the code you have written so far?

Comment: would it be possible to use side-by-side list box selections for your different constraints, then use a script that, upon selection of one constraint, resets the other constraints to "full open" (i.e. set to a value that encompasses the entire data range for the select column)